# jQuery validation is not happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have this script on my page:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#TotalHours').attr('name', 'TotalHours'); // jQuery validation requires field names to be set

        $.validator.addMethod("hours", function(value, element) {
            var totalHours = 0;
            $('select').each(function(i, sel) {
                var hours = $(sel).find(":selected").text();
                if (hours != "")
                    totalHours += parseFloat(hours);
            });
            var reportedTotalHours = parseFloat($("#TotalHours").text());
            var difference = abs(totalHours - reportedTotalHours);
            return difference >= 0.25; // discrepancy must be less than a quarter hour
        });

        $('form').bind('submit', function() {
            $("#TheForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    TotalHours: {
                        hours: true
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I had it working the other day but now when the form is submitted it is not validated (if I set a breakpoint inside the function I'm binding to `submit`, it never gets hit)... what could I have broken?

edit: here is the handler for the submit button, in case it helps:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function __E374_onclick(){
    try{$("#TheForm").validate();
    if(!$("#TheForm").valid()){alert('The data you have entered is not valid. Please complete all required fields and correct any data entry errors.'); return;}
    var pm=$("#TheForm").serialize();$.post("/Action/Do/", pm, function(d){
        switch(true){
            case (null==d):dm("The server returned an unexpected response.");break;
            case (!d.Valid):case (!d.Successful):dm(d.Message);break;
            case (d.Successful):dm(d.Message);fu("EditAssessment");break;
            default:dm("An unexpected condition occurred.");break;}});
}catch(e){}}
</script>
```

and the submit button itself:

```
<input type='button' id="__E374" class="button" value="Save" onclick="__E374_onclick();"/>
```

Comment: Changed ID's in the markup? No you are only binding to "form" so not that. I assume jQuery is loaded? What's in the console when you submit?

Comment: What's in the console when I submit? Not sure what you mean by that...

Comment: [`.bind()` has been deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) for a while, so what version of jQuery are you using?  You're not supposed to put the `.validate()` method inside of a `submit` handler - just refer to one of the 6000 working examples tagged with jQuery Validate on SO.  Secondly, where is the relevant and rendered HTML so we can try this out for ourselves?

Comment: I'm using jQuery v1.11.2, it looks like. I'm having trouble grabbing the HTML source because it's dynamically generated so it doesn't appear in View Source in my browser.

Comment: The browser DOM is dynamically updated so you look at the rendered HTML in the developer's tools, not the page source.  Maybe Google how to use the developer's console to troubleshoot and inspect.

Comment: Again `$('form').bind('submit'...` needs to go away entirely because capturing the submit event is already handled automatically within the plugin.

Comment: I tried removing the submit binding and calling `$("#TheForm").validate({` directly and the validation method is still not being called.

Comment: Could this have anything to do with the type of button I'm using? I'm using an `<input type='button'...>` to submit the form; the actual submission is being done in a JavaScript function called by the button's `onclick` handler. Is it possible that perhaps submitting the form in this way is breaking validation?

Comment: Yes.  `type="button"` will not submit the form.  You need a `type="submit"` or another handler function to programmatically trigger validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('form').bind('submit', function() {
    $("#TheForm").validate({
        ....
```

You cannot wrap `.validate()` inside of a submit handler.  The plugin is already automatically capturing the submit event so this is pointless; and it blocks the plugin from initializing itself on the form until the first submit event. *(BTW - jQuery `.bind()` has been deprecated)*

The `.validate()` method is used for initializing the plugin on your form and is called after the form is created, most typically within a `ready` event handler.

```
<input type='button' ....
```

The plugin ignores the click from a `<button>` and a `type="button"`.  You'll need to change this into a `type="submit"`.

Please refer to [the SO Wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) for typical usage and examples.

Comment: Changing the `<input type="button">` to `type="submit"` seems to have fixed it, thanks!